# the user's timezone is null when grabbing it in the mailboxsettings using the Graph SDK

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to call Graph SDK to access the user's timezone. In order to do that i created a native app that has two scopes (Read and readWrite user's mailboxsettings). However as you can see in the image the timezone prop is null, despite the fact that i successfully grabbed the user's timezone[image].

This is the code that i did :

```
 public static async Task TryGetUserMailboxSettingsAsync()
        {
            var graphClient = AuthenticationHelper.GetAuthenticatedClient();
            User user = await graphClient.Me.Request().Select("MailboxSettings").GetAsync();
            MailboxSettings mailboxSettings = user.MailboxSettings;
        }
```

Can anyone tell me why ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assume you want to get the timezone property using the Graph SDK.

First, we should set the mail setting at [here](https://portal.office.com//account/#settings). Then we can find the area of `your app settings` and find the Mail. Click it and set the timezone and the language.

Then, we use the code like you posted, the timezone property will not be null.